# Error exportando datos a Excel desde C#

Tags: c#, excel

Necesito exporter los datos de un `DataGriedView` a una hoja de Excel. Tengo el siguente código:

```
public void exportar(DataGridView dgv)
{
    try
    {
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xlsx)|*xlsx";
        fichero.FileName = "ArchivoExportado";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libro;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja;

            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libro = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libro.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            for (int i = 0; 1 < dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; 1 < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if ((dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                    {
                        hoja.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            libro.SaveAs(fichero.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libro.Close(true);
            aplicacion.Quit();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error"+ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Cuando doy clic en el boton `Exportar` me muestra un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La línea 551 es el if: `if ((dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)`

No sé cuál es el problema.

Comment: tu fallo está en `for (int i = 0; 1 < dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)` ya que `1< count` es siempre cierto. Lo mismo en el siguiente `for`. Has de poner `i` en vez de `1`. Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como *No relacionado: Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico.*

Comment: brother, si el comentario del buen @lois6b ha solucionado tu pregunta, por favor agrega la respuesta para colaborar con el crecimiento del sitio. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

No hagas uso del `for` para recorrer las rows del grid usa el `foreach`

```
int i = 1;
foreach (var row in dgv.Rows)
{
    int j = 1;
    foreach(var col in dgv.Columns)
    {
        if (row.Cells[col.Index].Value != null)
        {
            hoja.Cells[i, j] = row.Cells[col.Imdex].Value.ToString();
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Tambien recomendaria que evites de usar las librerias de interop del office para exportar a excel, usa unas basadas en open xml como ser

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

de esta forma no tendras problemas con COM y no requieres office instalado para poder exportar